# 415 unsupported media type error when posting to aspnetcore api from angular using $http

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

calling above using in Angular as:

```
 function Login(email, password, callback)  
 {  
        var GetAll = new Object();  
        GetAll.email = email;   
        GetAll.password = email;  
        $http({  
            url: "http://localhost:52587/api/TokenAuth/Login",  
            dataType: 'json',  
            method: 'post',  
            data: JSON.stringify(GetAll),       
            headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      }      
         }) 
      .then(function loginSuccessCallback(response)
 {...
```

I've tested this using swagger and ajax which worked fine. I set it up with json object in the body (set to raw and JSON (application/json)).

I have written the following Web API:

```
namespace WEBAPI.Controllers  
{   
    public class user  
    {   
        public string email { get; set; }   
        public string password { get; set; }  
    }

 [Produces("application/json")]   
 [Route("api/[controller]")]       
 public class TokenAuthController : Controller    
 {

  [HttpPost("Login")]    
  public async Task`<IActionResult>` Login([FromBody]user usr)   
{   
..................               
..................             
}      
}         
}
```

But I am getting [FromBody ] 415 unsupported media type and
without [FromBody] getting null parameter. Please help me
Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to JSON.stringify your data because what you really need is a JSON object. Making your data as a string will surely get you a 415 ( unsupported media type ) error.
You can do it like this

```
$http({  
            url: "http://localhost:52587/api/TokenAuth/Login",  
            dataType: 'json',  
            method: 'post',  
            data: GetAll,       
            headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      }      
      }) 
 .then(function loginSuccessCallback(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `accept` header

```
 headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Accept':  'application/json'
 }
```

Comment: I have also tried but i am getting 415 unsupported media type.